# Group Policy is not applying or being dected by certain users on the same doman

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, group-policy

I have recently been experiencing an issue when attempting to push out Group Policy updates.  The updates I am attempting to apply are basically just updating parameters in .txt file that resides on a user's PC.  These .txt files are used to control a program used by most all users on our domain.

This being said, when I attempt to update my PC by issuing the follow command:

```
gpupdate /force
```

Or if I log off and log back on, my .txt file is updated successfully.  I checked the Windows Event Viewer logs regarding Group Policy:

```
Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Group Policy/Operational
```

And found numerous logs statements.  It displays my account details, shows that I am connected to active directory, and lists the applicable group updates.  One thing I noticed that was strange was the following:

Check out my list of applicable updates:

[image]

It also lists the following in the logs:

[image]

Where WOC_Updates is the policy that I am wanting to apply.  It is a program written to perform the necessary PC updates.

On the affected PCs, I see the same account details, it shows that I am connected to active directory, and it lists the applicable group updates.  However it lists a different set of applicable group updates:

[image]

It also does not list the "Starting Scripts Extension Processing." statements like in the screenshot above as it does for successful PCs.

All users are on the same domain with the same permissions to the locations being accessed.  I am new to this area so any help on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT:  Adding screen capture of GPO setup:

[image]

Comment: Saying that all users are on the same domain isn't really saying anything. Are the affected user accounts within the scope of management of the GPO in question?

Comment: We have all of our users setup under different groups, all applied under the Security Filtering section of the GPO in question.  If I add the affected user's computer name to the Security Filtering section, the updates will apply, which is strange.  Also, I am in the same group as one of the users that is being affected, and the policy is working for me.  I am just trying to divulge some helpful information.  Please don't hesitate to ask for any clarification if this did not help answer your question.

Comment: `If I add the affected user's computer name to the Security Filtering section, the updates will apply, which is strange` - That makes it sound like the GPO settings are configured under Computer Configuration settings and not under User Configuration settings. If so then that's your problem. Computer settings apply to computers and User settings apply to users and never the twain shall meet. Can you post a screenshot of the GPO settings showing where they are? Either under Computer or User settings.

Comment: Added a screenshot via an edit to my original post above.

Comment: Did you removed authenticated user from the security group filtering on the GPO ? if so you need to set in the security of the GPO domain computer to read only to have the GPO work if so.

Comment: @yagmoth555: Yes. I completely forgot about that. I'm certain that you're correct.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3163622/ms16-072-security-update-for-group-policy-june-14,-2016

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3159398/ms16-072-description-of-the-security-update-for-group-policy-june-14,-2016

Comment: Thank you.  I think you may be onto something.  Authenticated Users is not a group listed under Security Filtering.  Do I change the permissions for a group under 'Delegation' for the group that has affected members?  Although why would it work for me if I am in the same group as another affected user?  The group we are under has 'Read (from Security Filtering)' listed as the allowed permissions.  What are the ramifications of adding 'Authenticated Users' back to the Security Filtering?

Comment: You can just add Domain Computer to the delegation, to read only, as Microsoft secured the GPO, thus the gpo can't be read by the computer, even if the user that log into the computer is member of the security's filter

Comment: A good blog post too, how to fix that error for ever too with ADSI Edit, if you create new GPO; https://www.gpanswers.com/never-a-dull-moment-with-group-policy-or-what-to-do-about-ms16-072/ :)

Comment: I added 'Domain Computers' to the delegation of the GPO as read only.  I did NOT add 'Domain Computers' to the scope however.  Is this correct?

Comment: Also, after applying changes to a group policy, how long should I wait to attempt to push the GPO out?

Comment: Yes, it's correct in deleguation only, and you can test right now after as it's a user GPO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you removed authenticated user from the security group filtering on the GPO, then you need to set in the security of the GPO domain computer to read only to have the GPO work.

As joeqwerty found the link, it's because of those update:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3163622/ms16-072-security-update-for-group-policy-june-14,-2016
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3159398/ms16-072-description-of-the-security-update-for-group-policy-june-14,-2016

You could use that powershell command too if you have a lot of GPO in that situation !

```
Get-GPO -All | Set-GPPermissions -TargetType Group -TargetName "Domain computers" -PermissionLevel GpoRead
```

For your last question, Adding Domain Computers “indirectly”, by using the Delegation tab advantage and disadvantage or Adding DOMAIN COMPUTERS to Security Filtering section advantage and disadvantage, please check that [blog](https://www.gpanswers.com/never-a-dull-moment-with-group-policy-or-what-to-do-about-ms16-072/) post, it explain it more, but each way would work (but he suggest the indirect method like I told you)